# How can I use parsley.js with Codeigniter form_open() function?

Tags: codeigniter, parsley.js, codeigniter-form-helper

Actually I want to pass  `data-parsley-validate` as a parameter to form_open() function.

Like `<form action="http://recruit.com/controller/add_jobs" accept-charset="utf-8" data-parsley-validate>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can init parsleyJS with jQuery:

```html
<form id="form"></form>

<script>
  $('#form').parsley();
</script>
```

So, you dont need to do `<form data-parsley-validate></form>`

Answer (score -2):

At first load parsley.js in the head of html.
then apply parsley.js in the CI like this:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" id="parsleyForm" data-parsley-validate 
  action="<?php echo site_url('.........') ?>">
```

go to [this link](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html) for details of `parsley.js`.

Comment: Finally It works.... `<?php  echo form_open('post_controller/add_jobs','data-parsley-validate'); ?>`